# Remove or Replace dynamic word from label

Tags: vb.net

I want to remove specific dynamic word in label
For sample :

```
label1.text = "Name1:<br />DYANMIC_NAME1<br />Name2:<br />DYNAMIC_NAME2"
```

i can remove the `Name1:<br />` and `<br />Name2:<br />` using

```
label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace("Name1:<br />", "").Trim
label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace("<br />Name2:<br />", "").Trim
```

my question is..
how can i remove or replace DYNAMIC_NAME1 and or DYNAMIC_NAME2
meaning of DYNAMIC is always change.. i hope you undestand.
can someone help me??
sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

Comment: you can use the same function isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you always get in the format:

```
"Name1:<br />DYANMIC_NAME1<br />Name2:<br />DYNAMIC_NAME2"
```

Here is what you can do:

```
label1.text = "Name1:<br />DYANMIC_NAME1<br />Name2:<br />DYNAMIC_NAME2"

'Split the string and use <br /> as the separator
Dim result As String() = label1.text.Split(New String() {"<br />"}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

'Now you know that at indices 1 and 3, you have your two dynamic words.
label1.text = label1.text.Replace(result(1), "")
label1.text = label1.text.Replace(result(3), "")
```

Please note that I haven't run and tested it but it should give you the idea about what I am trying to do here.

**EDIT** (as per the suggestion by Dominic Kexel):

```
label1.text = "Name1:<br />DYANMIC_NAME1<br />Name2:<br />DYNAMIC_NAME2"

Dim separator As String() = New String() {"<br />"}
Dim result As String() = label1.text.Split(separator)

Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
For i As Integer = 0 To result.Length - 1
    If i <> 1 And i <> 3 Then
        sb.Append(result(i))
    End If

    If i < result.Length - 1 Then
        sb.Append(separator(0))
    End If
Next

label1.text = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if any of the strings that are going to be replaced are e.g. `Name`; so `"Name1:<br />Name<br />Name2:<br />FooBar"` will result in `"1:<br /><br />Name2:<br />"`.

Comment: @DominicKexel - though it is highly unlikely that the actual name contains `Name` as a string but an alternative can be to use a loop. I'll edit my answer shortly. Thanks